# How to get access to containers' event from user control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to rise parents' **SizeChange** event from my user control (AdvancedButton).I need to change my user controls' size if containers' size will be changed.But I don't know how I can get access to containers' events.I tried this way:

```
public AdvancedButton()
    {            
        Form1 frm = (Form1)this.FindForm();
        frm.SizeChanged += OnFormSizeChanged;

        DoubleBuffered = true;
        MouseDown += OnMouseDown;
        MouseUp += OnMouseUp;
        MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
        Click += OnClick;
    }

    private void OnFormSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Width += this.Width - 1;
        this.Height += this.Height - 1;
    }
```

But this way doesn't work,when I try to launch application.There is the errors' text: **An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Kyrsovoi.exe**

I found one way that works but it is not way I need, because of here we must write **FindForm()** in Form1.Designer.cs:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        ...
        this.AdvancedButton1 = new WindowFormsApplication1.AdvancedButton(FindForm());
        ...
    }
```

MyButton.cs code:

```
public AdvancedButton(Form parent)
    {
        parent.SizeChanged += OnFormSizeChanged;
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        MouseDown += OnMouseDown;
        MouseUp += OnMouseUp;
        MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
        Click += OnClick;
    }

    private void OnFormSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Width += this.Width - 1;
        this.Height += this.Height - 1;
    }
```

Please,help.Maybe someone knows any ways to solve this task.

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use the `Anchor` or `Dock` properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move parent event-related code to OnParentChanged:

```
protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnParentChanged(e);

    if (this.Parent != null)
    {
        this.Parent.SizeChanged += OnFormSizeChanged; // this.ParentForm.SizeChanged += ...
    }
}

void OnFormSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...
}
```

Consider using Anchor/Dock/Margin properties for layout.